# rsyslog output module to azure log analytics

Tags: azure, rsyslog, azure-log-analytics

I have few containers running and I am sending logs from these to a rsyslog server via docker logging-driver.
Now is there a way wherein I can send these logs from the rsyslog server to Azure log analytics?
I do not see any output module for rsyslog to write to it

Comment: Could you please review this documentation , if not already -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-syslog#rsyslog to see if it fits your scenario. Thank you

Comment: @Nipun, have you solved the issue as per the comment above?

Comment: @IvanYang : I am not using rsyslog but now using fluentd to send it to grafana loki.

Comment: @Nipun, then does it work when using fluentd to send it to grafana loki? If it's working, please post an answer. And if you still have issues, please update your post, then we'd like to assist you:)

Comment: I have used a different approach than this one so I think this may still valid. We can close this for now

Comment: Hello @Nipun, I added an answer to close this question. could you please accept it as answer to close the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize to close the question.

To send these logs from the rsyslog server to Azure log analytics, you can refer to this official doc [rsyslog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-syslog#rsyslog).

And you can also use the solution by using fluentd which is provided by op.